# call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, contract-development

I'm unable to compile a small test contract and am hoping for guidance.  I have a class called Account, in the following 2 files:

```
// --- account.hpp 
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosio/system.hpp>
#include <eosio/asset.hpp>
#include <eosio/singleton.hpp>
#include <eosio/transaction.hpp>

namespace myapp {
    using namespace eosio;

    class Account {
        private:

        struct [[eosio::table]] _balances {
            asset value;
            uint64_t primary_key() const {
                return value.symbol.code().raw();
            }   
        };  
        typedef multi_index<name("balances"), _balances> EOST;
        EOST t;

        public:

        class Balance {
            public:

            Balance(EOST t, symbol sym);
            int64_t sat = 0;
            double amt = 0;
        };  

        Account(name code, name acct);
        Balance bal(asset o); 
        Balance bal(symbol sym);
    };  
}
```

and

```
// --- account.cpp
#include "account.hpp"

namespace myapp {
    using namespace eosio;
    Account::Balance::Balance(EOST t, symbol sym) {
        auto o = t.find(sym.code().raw());
        if (o != t.end()) {
            sat = o->value.amount;
            amt = o->value.amount / pow(10, o->value.symbol.precision());
        }
    }
    Account::Account(name code, name acct)
        : t(code, acct.value) {
    }
    Account::Balance Account::bal(asset o) {
        return bal(o.symbol);
    }   
    Account::Balance Account::bal(symbol sym) {
        return Balance(this->t, sym);
    }       
}
```

which I then use from my contract quite simply like this:

```
// --- token.cpp
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosio/system.hpp>
#include <eosio/asset.hpp>
#include <eosio/singleton.hpp>
#include <eosio/transaction.hpp>

#include "account.cpp"

namespace eosiosystem {
    class system_contract;
}

namespace eosio {
    class [[eosio::contract("token")]] token : public contract {
    public:
        [[eosio::action]] void ping() {
            myapp::Account acct(_self, name("cust1"));
            myapp::Account::Balance b = acct.bal(symbol("USD", 8));
            print("\nbalance = ", b.sat, ", ", b.amt);
        }   
    };  
}
```

however, the code won't compile, citing the aforementioned error:

> In file included from /Users/ekkis/dev/eos/account/token.cpp:3: In
>   file included from
>   /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/libcxx/string:470:
>   In file included from
>   /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/libcxx/string_view:169:
>   In file included from
>   /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/libcxx/__string:56:
>   In file included from
>   /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/libcxx/algorithm:643:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/libcxx/memory:1759:31:
>   error: 
>         call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of
>         'eosio::multi_index<4152997948076064768,
>         myapp::Account::_balances>::item_ptr'
>               ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
>                                 ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/libcxx/memory:1670:18:
>   note: 
>         in instantiation of function template specialization
>         'std::__1::allocator::item_ptr>::construct::item_ptr,
>         eosio::multi_index<4152997948076064768,
>         myapp::Account::_balances>::item_ptr &>' requested here
>               {__a.construct(__p, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);}
>                    ^ /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/libcxx/memory:1516:14:
>   note: 
>         in instantiation of function template specialization
>         'std::__1::allocator_traits::item_ptr>
>
> > ::__construct::item_ptr,
> >           eosio::multi_index<4152997948076064768,
> >           myapp::Account::_balances>::item_ptr &>' requested here
> >                 {__construct(__has_construct(),
> >                  ^ /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/libcxx/memory:1600:17:
> >     note: 
> >           in instantiation of function template specialization
> >           'std::__1::allocator_traits::item_ptr>
> >     ::construct::item_ptr,
> >           eosio::multi_index<4152997948076064768,
> >           myapp::Account::_balances>::item_ptr &>' requested here
> >                     construct(__a, _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(__begin2), *__begin1);
> >                     ^ /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/libcxx/vector:1030:21:
> >     note: 
> >           in instantiation of function template specialization
> >           'std::__1::allocator_traits::item_ptr>
> >     ::__construct_range_forward::item_ptr *,
> >           eosio::multi_index<4152997948076064768,
> >           myapp::Account::_balances>::item_ptr *>' requested here
> >         __alloc_traits::__construct_range_forward(__a, __first, __last, this...
> >                         ^ /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/libcxx/vector:1213:9:
> >     note: 
> >           in instantiation of function template specialization
> >           'std::__1::vector::item_ptr,
> >           std::__1::allocator::item_ptr>
> >     ::__construct_at_end::item_ptr *>' requested here
> >             __construct_at_end(__x.__begin_, __x.__end_, __n);
> >             ^ /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/eosiolib/contracts/eosio/multi_index.hpp:431:7:
> >     note: 
> >           in instantiation of member function
> >           'std::__1::vector::item_ptr,
> >           std::__1::allocator::item_ptr> >::vector' requested here class multi_index
> >           ^ /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/eosiolib/contracts/eosio/multi_index.hpp:474:32:
> >     note: 
> >           copy constructor of 'item_ptr' is implicitly deleted because field '_item'
> >           has a deleted copy constructor
> >              std::unique_ptr _item;
> >                                    ^ /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/libcxx/memory:2388:3:
> >     note: 
> >           copy constructor is implicitly deleted because
> >           'unique_ptr::item,
> >           std::__1::default_delete::item> >' has a user-declared move constructor   unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& __u) noexcept   ^ Warning, empty
> >     ricardian clause file Warning, empty ricardian clause file Warning,
> >     action  does not have a ricardian contract 1 error generated.
> >     Error while processing /Users/ekkis/dev/eos/account/token.cpp. abigen
> >     error

from which the error **copy constructor of 'item_ptr' is implicitly deleted because field '_item' has a deleted copy constructor std::unique_ptr _item** stands out.  but I'm no brighter for it as to what the issue could be

help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah.  the problem is that the EOS table must be passed by reference:

```
Account::Balance::Balance(EOST &t, symbol sym) {
```